# ScraperWiki: simple_html_dom library

Tags: scraperwiki

I would like to know if the simple_html_dom library from ScraperWiki:

```
require 'scraperwiki/simple_html_dom.php';
```

Is the same or uses the same methods as this one:

[PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

I want to know this because it would be an easy way to try the scrapers at ScraperWiki in local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are the same.

if you run a new scraper in scraperwiki with this code:

```
echo `/usr/bin/md5sum "../scraperwiki/php/scraperwiki/simple_html_dom.php"`;
```

You can obtain the md5 sum of the file they are using. i.e. `fa249f6c0a0bc274631b8d606817f49d`

And if you download the file from sourceforge and use a local php file with this code:

```
echo hash_file('md5', 'simple_html_dom.php');
```

You can obtain the md5 sum of the file on sourceforge. i.e. `fa249f6c0a0bc274631b8d606817f49d`

As you can see both are the same :D

p.s. yes, scraperwiki seems to run code in `` ` `` :O